# How to obtain "X-Forwarded-Proto" header in REST application?

Tags: java, web-services, http, rest, jax-ws

I have a REST application running on tomcat. I am forwarding http requests to https using server.xml `redirectPort` parameter.

Now, on the server side, I want to read the **X-Forwarded-Proto** header to identify if requests are being redirected.

My code looks like this:

```
@Context
UriInfo uriInfo;

@Context
Request request;

protected Response checkRedirect(SecurityContext sc)
{

   String forwardedProtocol = ((ContainerRequest)request).getHeaderValue("X-Forwarded-Proto");

}
```

However, this does not work. It seems like the request object only gives access to handful of http headers.

Can someone please suggest the best way I can obtain the header value? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [instruct](http://paulgraydon.co.uk/blog/2012/10/30/helping-tomcat-understand-x-forwarded-proto/) the tomcat to pay attention.

Comment: Sorry, I am still not clear on how to retrieve the http header value in my java app. Can you shed some light on that?

Comment: Your code should be good. You need to go to tomcat/conf/server.xml, and add the entries to tell tomcat to capture the Header.

Comment: This thing still doesn't work. I am still not able to retrieve the value in the server side.

Comment: The URL is not found. It is common to add a self-contained answer in stackoverflow. Maybe it is possible that you can sum-up the contents of that page here?